# select x no. of items from a long array and display more on scroll in a tableview

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, swift2

I need to display say 10 items from a list of 500 items which is stored in an array, and when the user scrolls to the bottom most cell of the tableview the next 10 items are loaded in the same tableview so now the tableview has 20 items and this continues until it has been scrolled 50 times and the tableview has 500 items

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can just store the 500 items in the array and set the long array as the data source for your tableview. When the user scrolls down to the bottom cell, the delegates will pretty much take care of reloading new items from the array.

However, if you really want to do the whole pagination thing, you can use the `willDisplayCell` method to determine if the cell about to be displayed is the last cell.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

 // let say currentArray (which is your data source) only has 10 items
 // currentArray = [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]

 // if cell indexPath.row is the same index as max element of currentArray
 // it is the last cell in the table
 if indexPath.row == currentArray.count - 1 {

   // get next 10 items
   let nextTenItemsArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
   currentArray = currentArray + nextTenItemsArray
 }

}
```

Do note that my codes are just to illustrate the underlying logic needed to achieve what you asked in the question.

Comment: Will display cell isnt working in my thing for some reason code:
 `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
let cel = self.ntab.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ncell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! table
 cel.arr.text = s[indexPath.row] return cel }
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, ForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
 if (indexPath.row + 1) == s.count { 
print("Displayed the last row!") 
}
 }`

Comment: `willDisplayCell` is a method outside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, it is a `UITableView` delegate, try taking out the `func willDisplayCell` method and see if it works.